# neo4j Grass documentation? Trying to set node size from a property

Tags: neo4j, visualization, grass

Is this possible using .grass?
I made a property called diameter and set it to "50px" on a node, but it doesn't work. The nodes just disappear.

```
"node.User": {
    "color": "#FB95AF",
    "border-color": "#E0849B",
    "text-color-internal": "#FFFFFF",
    "caption": "{name}",
    "diameter": "{diameter}"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes shouldn't be used

Example: `

```
node.User{
  color: #FF756E;
  border-color: #E06760;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF; 
  diameter:25
}
```

`